# HTTP Impressions increasing in Search Console since move to HTTPS

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

In August last year I moved a site to HTTPS. I have recently noticed that I am still getting impressions for HTTP pages in Search Console. In fact the number of clicks and impressions seems to be increasing since the beginning of this year.

[image: HTTP Traffic]

I did not do a map of 301's from every HTTP to HTTPS URL, however I did add this to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

I thought maybe this was the problem so just over a week ago I added a direct 301 redirect from one HTTP page to the corresponding HTTPS page, but I don't see that this is making a difference to that URL:

[image: Joburg Traffic]

I'm worried that Google is seeing this as duplicate content, as our overall traffic on the domain has been decreasing:

[image: Overall Traffic]

It could also be due to the fact that we haven't really created much in the way of new content for the last few years. But I just wanted to ask here if anyone has any idea why these URLs which should be redirected are gaining in traffic. If you try to go to any of the HTTP URLs then they do redirect correctly, so I'm confused..

Comment: It took Google about 9 months to index all my pages on HTTPS for a 60,000 page site. It doesn't happen instantly unfortunately.

Comment: It could be that you have a lot of links to the http version of your site - if so, it could help speed up the process if you reach out to all the sites that link to yours and have them update the links there as well. But since human visitors are reaching the correct pages, I wouldn't worry about it too much. Search Console can be misleading in that it alerts you to things that look like errors, but as long as the humans are getting where they need to go, and your site is still appearing organically, you don't need to worry if things aren't exactly as you'd wish in SC.

Comment: I'd double check a few of the URLs reported in the http site and see if they do in fact 301 redirect to the correct page on the https site.